# Extract Values from HTML Page with Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, html-parsing

I am trying to extract values from an HTML page.  When the page contains simple tables, I can pull those fine using the following code:

```
Sub Export_HTML_Table_To_Excel()
    Dim htm As Object
    Dim Tr As Object
    Dim Td As Object
    Dim Tab1 As Object
    Dim Web_URL As String
    Dim wsgfLPARs As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim icol As Integer
    Dim Column_Num_To_Start As Integer
    Dim iTable As Integer
    Dim HTML_Content As Variant
    
    Set wsgfLPARs = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    
    Web_URL = "http://10.201.xxx.yy/iotdashboard/htmlibm/top/all_lpars.html"
    
    'Create HTMLFile Object
    Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", Web_URL, False
        .send
        HTML_Content.Body.Innerhtml = .responseText
    End With

    Column_Num_To_Start = 1
    irow = 0
    icol = Column_Num_To_Start
    iTable = 0

    'Loop Through Each Table and Download it to Excel in Proper Format
    For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")
        With HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")(iTable)
            For Each Tr In .Rows
                If Tr.Cells(1).innerText <> "" Then
                    For Each Td In Tr.Cells
                        wsgfLPARs.Cells(irow, icol).Select
                        wsgfLPARs.Cells(irow, icol) = Td.innerText
                        icol = icol + 1
                    Next Td
                    icol = Column_Num_To_Start
                    irow = irow + 1
                End If
            Next Tr
        End With
        iTable = iTable + 1
        icol = Column_Num_To_Start
        irow = irow + 1
    Next Tab1
End Sub
```

However, now I am trying to extract specific numbers from other webpages that contain more than simple tables.  The page looks like this:

[image: Web Page]

I am trying to pull the values for the Logical CPU that appear under the graph.  When I pull the HTML (using Inspect from Chrome), the values appear in the following tags:

```
<tr class="css-47yhhe-LegendRow"><td><span class="css-fblkr"><div class="pointer" style="background: rgb(115, 191, 105); width: 14px; height: 4px; border-radius: 1px; display: inline-block; margin-right: 8px;"></div><div class="css-w166kv-LegendLabel-LegendClickable">Idle </div></span></td><td class="css-1bpvq0r">93.0%</td><td class="css-1bpvq0r">95.9%</td><td class="css-1bpvq0r">97.3%</td><td class="css-1bpvq0r">29.9%</td></tr>
```

I realize I may not have posted enough of the HTML, but it gets really long, so I cut it to just the section with the values for which I am looking.

I have tried using: getElementsByTagName, getElementsByClassName, and getElementsByID without success.  However, I admit I am not sure what I should even be passing as arguments in the calls.

Can anyone please help me determine what I should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will print the rows for your table in the Immediate Window...

```
With HTML_Content.querySelectorAll("tr.css-47yhhe-LegendRow")
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = 0 To .Length - 1
        With .Item(rowIndex)
            Debug.Print Trim(.Cells(0).innerText), .Cells(1).innerText, .Cells(2).innerText, .Cells(3).innerText, .Cells(4).innerText
        End With
    Next rowIndex
End With
```

Comment: Thank you.  However, I am getting Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method on:
With HTML_Content.querySelectorAll("tr.css-47yhhe-LegendRow")

Comment: It looks like the website contains dynamic content.  If so, you'll need to use a different approach.  Try using Selenium instead.  You can search Google for some examples.

Comment: Thank you again Domenic.  
I got past the error 438 by declaring HTML_Content As HTMLDocument and adding the Microsoft HTML Object Library to my references.  While that removed the error, it still didn't find the desired lines (.Length = 0), as you said, perhaps because the page is dynamically generated.  I appreciate your suggestion to use Selenium.  I am looking into that now. If I can get it working (and get permission to install Selenium on my work pc), I will post the results here.  Thank you for your help.